# POST variables are disabled when action="http://..."

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I have a form that points (action) to an url: **`http://www.mysite.com/actions/process.php?id=12`**. In this case the post variables are not detected. If I change the url to: **`actions/process.php?id=12`** all works fine.

The big problem is that my form is situated into an include file and the directory of the output files (the pages with the form inside) may change their directory and for this reason I need to use the full url.

But with the full url POST doesn't work...

I forgot to say that the form is submitted by javascript:

```
document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

With a normal form it works fine even with a full url...but not if submitted with javascript! I use javascript because of the design of the submit button, I'm forced to do so.

PS: no errors in javascript console

How can I fix it?

PS: I'm working on Ubuntu server with apache installed

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by `But with the full url POST doesn't work...`, I wouldn't expect any change in behaviour.

Comment: http://.....process.php is the full url.

Comment: Did you do `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Have you tried just saying `/actions/process.php?id=12`?  (relative to the root of the site; should be as good as absolute)

Comment: There is probably a redirect happening at the point of the request. It might be worth looking at the network tab in chrome and seeing what happens at the point it submits.

Comment: I'm not working locally, the result of var_dump is NULL with a php error "Undefined index"

Comment: In case of full URL, does the request reach the server? Are there any errors in JavaScript console?

Comment: no errors in javascript console

Comment: +1 to cHao. I haven't tested recently, but my understanding is that putting a `/` first will position the URL relative to the host.

Comment: Perfect it works!! so by putting "/" at the beginning of the url is fine :)